# Can 'attributes' change its value after setting value to a property?

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, attributes

Consider this code:

```
Public Class SomeViewModel
    <Custom>
    Public Property myData As String
End Class
```

I want the `Custom` attribute to have capability to change myData after it set to some data.
ie. trim myData or omit extra chars from it or ...  it doesn't matter now.

I know I can use `set` and `get` statement, but those make my code look like not good, and also I want to repeat this `CustomAttribute` many times is same class or elsewhere.

**UPDATE**
Ok, if there is no way else, can I use some `customAttribute` and before my 'insert to SQL logic' call a function say: for all property that has this `customAttribute` do `this thing`? How can I implement that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use setters and getters, that's what they are for.

Attributes mark parts of your code, such that reflection can be used on this code - it is a rather heavy weight approach just because you don't like the look of property setters and getters.

Comment: I have 10 same property in that class and I want to do the same to them, that make my code such a messy code, isn't it?

Comment: @GtEx - Write a method that does this same thing and pass `value` to it. To be honest, without seeing this "same" you want to do, it is difficult to give any recommendation.

Comment: by `do the same` I mean one thing at a time like `trim`. I don't mind if it doesn't change exactly after set, I just want it before my insert to SQL logic.

Comment: @GtEx - Again, what properties are designed for. You may want to look at the [`DataAnnotations`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx) namespace, it might have what you are looking for.

Comment: I want to convert numbers from `persian` to `english` thats what I want and I know how to do it, so it wasn't part of the question :). I have registration form with lots of this kind of fields,(phone,cell,fax,zip,...), so any better option? thanks

Comment: Yes I am aware of DataAnnotation, they are usually for validation not for editing which is my purpose. I have respect for `dry code` which is `don't repeat yourself` :)

Comment: Ok, if there is no way else, can I use some `customAttribute` and before my `insert to SQL logic` call a function say: for all property that has this `customAttribute` do `this thing`? How can I implement that?

Comment: @GtEx - Again, without reflection, not really. Attributes just mark code. Some software like PostSharp can inject code when your compile your application, depending on the attributes you set. Might be worth a look.

Comment: I get confused, If attributes can mark my property so I can found out if a property has a specific attribute, right? I don't want to do something beyond, I think the language itself provide this feature, doesn't it?

Comment: @GtEx - You mark it and it does nothing. The compiler and other tools can look at the code and do something (and in many cases, with the built in attributes, they do stuff).

Comment: Ok, seems to me there is no way :(, I wont insist further. thanks for your time ;)